# Save Xml into SQL preserving accents

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, non-ascii-characters

I am using log4Net and SQL Server 2008 for storing XMLs responses from an external service.
In the responses there are spanish characters, like É, but when it is stored in a table that have a column type xml I get Ã‰

In config I have mapped the parameter like this:

```
<parameter>
    <parameterName value="@message"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="-1"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
```

How can I store and preserve accents??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There wasn´t a problem with log4net or SQL.
The problem was that in fiddler web service responses were correct. But the process that consumes the web service was using a code like this:

```
var webclient = new WebClient ();
var response = webClient.UploadString (url, method, data);
```

Adding:

```
webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
```

before making the upload string makes this working properly